# WebView is blocking my ExpandableListView's expansion

Tags: android, webview, expandablelistview

I've been working with ExpandableListViews before and I know about checkBoxes, Buttons, etc.

It is essential to setFocusable to false for any of these widgets that could be found on the XML that will serve as a groupView of our list, othervise, clicking on the group cell will not expand the group, since these widgets will steal focus from it.

BUT, If I put WebView in my GroupView, and **setFocusable** & **setFocusableInTouchMode** to **false**, I will still **NOT** be able to expand the group.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="91dp"
   android:background="#ffffff">

<ImageView
   android:layout_width="30dp"
   android:layout_height="91dp"
   android:id="@+id/sth_cell_img_correct"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   android:src="@drawable/icon_checked" />

<WebView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
   android:focusable="false"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
   android:id="@+id/webView2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But, if I **remove** WebView from the XML, I **can** expand / shrink cells with no trouble whatsoever.

There must be some other thing I should do here. Some other attribute should be set to false, or something like that, but I cannot figure out what exactly.

Does anyone has a clue what to do in order to have WebView in group XML and be able to expand the group itself ?

Comment: why would you need a WebView....what you want to do with web view here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting this on the root element

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

And then make the WebView unclickable with

```
android:clickable="false"
```

The final XML should be something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="91dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:background="#ffffff">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="91dp"
    android:id="@+id/sth_cell_img_correct"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_checked" />

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:id="@+id/sth_web_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Saved my day @pixelsize